# Brave & Chrome SSB for Windows like Epichrome on macOS?

Tags: web-browser, chrome

Epichrome is really an awesome tool for allowing us to created dedicated Chrome (and now Brave [in beta](https://www.patreon.com/epichrome/posts)) apps on macOS. [Coherence](https://www.bzgapps.com/coherencepro) appears to also do this for Chrome. I don't use it for just SSB purposes anymore, but also to isolate projects and research since it works so well for consolidation and lessening primary browser bloat / clutter.

Are there any such options for Windows?